# Is there any better way other than checking every single cells in a column of data?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

[In Column A and B, I have "date and time" and "hourly measurement" data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6tLF.png)

Column A indicates the date and time, and B is the measured data on hourly basis. What I wanted to do is to calculate daily averages.

What I did is adding column C showing the number of the day of a month, adding column D calculating the daily averages of data on column B, and adding column E for extracting the daily average in daily basis.

My code is:

```
Sub dailyAverages ()

Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = "=DAY(A2)"
    
Range("D1") = "daily average"
Range("D13:D" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 11).Value = "=AVERAGE(B2:B25)"
    
    
Range("E1") = "IF"
Range("E2").Select
        
        Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Value = ""
        
        myCell1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2)
        myCell2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2)
    
            If myCell1 <> myCell2 Then
            ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
                    
        Loop

End Sub
```

The code gets the work done, however, it runs somewhat slow because the if statement checks the rows one by one and the number of data can reach up to 130 00 rows in some files.

I am a very beginner on VBA. Is there any faster way how to do so?

Comment: Seems like AVERAGEIF() would work here?

Comment: You could probably also use a Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. The [AVERAGEIF() function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) accepts 3 parameters, the cell range containing the desired criteria, the criteria to look for, and the cell range to average. In this case, *[average_range]* is not optional.

```
AVERAGEIF(range, criteria, [average_range])
```

Based on the layout you described, columns D&E would use a *single row* to report an average for *each day*, and column C&E would calculate the following. Note that E4's criteria is C19, the first cell containing the next day number:

```
C3=DAY(A3)
E3=AVERAGEIF(C3:C34,C3,B3:B34)

C4=DAY(A4)
E4=AVERAGEIF(C3:C34,C19,B3:B34)

etc
```

[image: Demonstration]

Answer (score 0):

As [Rod Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) commented, you can use a [pivot chart/table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivotchart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c). This is easy. Very little [maintenance](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-source-data-for-a-pivottable-afd93524-f7de-432c-84d0-3896fbbc2577) is required.

**Img: Change Data in a Pivot Table**
[image: Change Data in a Pivot Table]